Why Does an Element in All Subsets Belong to A∖(B∖C)?
I’m working through set operations and I came across a concept that I'm struggling to fully grasp. Specifically, I'm trying to understand why an element that belongs to all the subsets A, B, and C would also belong to A∖(B∖C).
Here's the expression in question: A∖(B∖C).

To break it down:
What does B∖C represent?
It includes all elements that are in B but not in C.
What does A∖(B∖C) represent?
It includes all elements that are in A but not in B∖C.
Why would an element that is in all of A, B, and C necessarily be in A∖(B∖C)? What if it would be A∖(B u C), would the element in A, B and C be still part of it?
I’d appreciate a detailed explanation of why elements present in all three sets A, B, and C end up being in A∖(B∖C). Thank you!

What happens when we take an element of set B? It will be in $A \cap B \cap C$, but it seems to be not in second subset without additional relations beetween A,B and C

@AdamWrzesiński $B$ is not contained in $A \cap B \cap C$.

Consider an element that's in all three of $A,B,C$. Then, being in $C$, it can't be in $B\setminus C$. And, being in $A$ but not in $B\setminus C$, it's in $A\setminus(B\setminus C)$.

If an element is contained in $A,B,C$ then it is obviously in $A$ and at the same time it can’t be in $B \setminus C$ since otherwise it is not $C$. Hence the element is in $A \setminus (B \setminus C)$

I don't quite understand what you mean.

@thescandinavian_programmer $~\neg (B\setminus ~C)~$ is equivalent to $~[ ~(\neg B)~\text{or} ~C].~$ So, the overall expression is equivalent to the compound assertions that the element must be in $~A~$ and the element is either not in $~B,~$ or the element is in $~C.$

Note that
$$
x \notin B \setminus C \iff x \notin B \text{ or } x \in C.
$$
Hence,
\begin{align}
x \in A \setminus (B \setminus C)
&\iff x \in A \text{ and } x \notin B \setminus C \\
&\iff x \in A \text{ and } (x \notin B \text{ or } x \in C) \\
&\iff (x \in A \text{ and } x \notin B) \text{ or } (x \in A \text{ and } x \in C).
\end{align}
Thus, if $x$ belongs to $A$, $B$ and $C$, the second parenthesis above is true, so that $x \in A \setminus (B \setminus C)$.


What does B∖C represent? It includes all elements that are in B but not in C.

Exactly

What does A∖(B∖C) represent? It includes all elements that are in A but not in B∖C.

A(B\C) is all the elements in A that are not in B\C. And then we can use the first question to say that it is all the elements in A that are not in $B$ unless they are in C because elements in C are not in B\C.

Why would an element that is in all of A, B, and C necessarily be in A∖(B∖C)? What if it would be A∖(B u C), would the element in A, B and C be still part of it?

From the previous question in an element is part of all 3 sets it will be in A∖(B∖C). But I don’t completely understand the second question if an element is in A∖(B u C) then it is in A and not in B or C. So it would have to be in A∖(B ∖ C). But an element in all 3 sets would be in (B u C) so it would not be in A∖(B u C).
